# When publishing react app on GitHub, should I make two different repositories for frontend and backend or only one repository?

Tags: github, repository

I have created an web app using reactjs and nodejs,
I want to publish it on github
I want to know should I make two different repositories for frntend and backend code,
include them in a single repository ?